# Changing Table Ownership in Postgres from Postgres User

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a database with some tables that was created by a certain user. All tables and sequences in that DB were owned by that user. I needed to change the owner of those tables and sequences to be able to run certain operations (Django Migrations).

In doing so, I changed it to `postgres` by mistake:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY delme TO postgres;
```

Now, when I attempt to correct the oversight, I get the following:

```
db_name=# REASSIGN OWNED BY postgres TO django_development;       
ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system
```

How can I change ownership of that entire db's contents to `django_development` user?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that the `postgres` user also owns all system catalogs and you can't reassign ownership for them.

You will need to do this manually for each table in each schema you have.

I would first do it for the schemas:

```
alter schema public owner to django_development;  
... repeat for all schemas
```

Then do it for all tables in the schemas using something like the following (not tested):

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_rec in select schemaname, tablename
               from pg_tables
               where schemaname in ('public', .... ) --<< adjust for your schemas
                 and tableowner = 'postgres'
  loop 
    l_sql := format('alter table %I.%I owner to django_development', l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.tablename);
    raise notice 'Running %: ', l_sql;
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

If you have other objects (views, functions, etc) you will need to something equivalent for them as well.

Comment: In other words, there is no way to avoid the pain in the neck? :/

Comment: No, there is no better way.

Comment: the above code works once you end it as suggested by @mustaccio! I am now wondering how to adopt this to sequences? `pg_sequence` has no identifier for a sequence's owner, so there is missing the handle.

Comment: @vrms every sequence also has an entry in `pg_class` You can change the above script to get the information from there and applying a WHERE condition on `pg_class.relkind` to pick the types you want.

Comment: thx @a_horse_with_no_name. I figured out something via `pg_sequences`, which seems to be a view combining `pg_sequence` with `pg_class` (if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect as the postgres user to be able change the objects owner back, or if you have another superuser account that should also work too.

Comment: I do connect as `postgres` but still get the above scenario.

Comment: Hmm do you have a superuser account you can connect as and try?