# changing ownership of tables owned by postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying the change ownership of tables owned by postgres user to another role based on an answer in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279387/changing-table-ownership-in-postgres-from-postgres-user/279391#279391).

concrete

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_rec in select schemaname, tablename
               from pg_tables
               where schemaname in ('public')
                 and tableowner = 'postgres'
  loop
    l_sql := format('alter table %I.%I owner to new_role', l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.tablename);
    raise notice 'Running %: ', l_sql;
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
```

running this however results into nothing more then changing the prompt from `[db_name]=#` to `[db_name]$#`. I could not figure out yet, wat the `$` stands for though. It's not PROMPT2 (which is `-#`).

I do not understand the code above in detail but would suspect the `%I.%I` in the `alter table` section maybe not resolving to to the desired content, or maybe the varialbe declaration not doing what it should.

Can anyone point me towards a solution for this?

Comment: or is it that you have to close the `begin` with a `commit` rather then `end`?

Comment: You started the block with `$$` but forgot to end it.

Comment: _I do not understand the code above in detail_ -- this is not a very good position to be in, when you run code copied from the internets in your database.

Answer (score 0):

based on the comment of @mustaccio 's above this is how it works

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_rec in select schemaname, tablename
               from pg_tables
               where schemaname in ('public')
                 and tableowner = 'postgres'
  loop
    l_sql := format('alter table %I.%I owner to new_role', l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.tablename);
    raise notice 'Running %: ', l_sql;
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end
$$
;
```